# Why is my columnfilter not filtering?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am trying to use columnfilter on a page.  On one page this filtering works perfict but on this page it does not.  I’ve tried coppying the same script urls from the page that works, I tried dragging from the list of scripts on to the page but still nothing.

NOTE:  The page has the search header and footer fields and it does response when I put the search text in but it returns nothing.  I get: “Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from 10 total entries)”…every time.

What could I be doing wrong or missing?  Thanks for any help with this one>

```
    <link href="../../Content/dataTable/the_table.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/DataTables-1.9.1/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js" type  ="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".datefield").datepicker();
       $("#history").dataTable().focus().columnFilter({
          aoColumns: [null, { type: "text" },null , null, null, null]
       });
    });
    </script>

    <br /><br />

    @Html.ActionLink("Select", "ClassAttendance", "Attendance", new { rows = Model.Enrollments.Count(),  id = @ViewBag.ID, teacher = HttpContext.Current.Session["sTeacher"], courseID = HttpContext.Current.Session["sCourseID"] }, null)

    <p></p>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ClassAttendance", "Attendance", new { rows = Model.Enrollments.Count(),  id = @ViewBag.ID, sTeacher = @ViewBag.teacherName, courseID = HttpContext.Current.Session["sCourseID"] }, FormMethod.Post))

    {

    var attend = new Enrollment();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <p></p>

    <h3>Students Enrolled in @ViewBag.teacherName's @ViewBag.courseTitle class</h3>  
    <div>
       <table id=history>  
          <thead>
             <tr>  
                <th>Reports</th> 
                <th>First Name</th>  
                <th>Last Name</th> 
                <th>Grade</th>  
                <th>Attendance Code</th>  
                <th>Class Day</th> 
             </tr>  
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
             <tr>  
                <td>Reports</td> 
                <td>First Name</td>  
                <td>Last Name</td> 
                <td>Grade</td>  
                <td>Attendance Code</td>  
                 <td>Class Day</td> 
             </tr>  
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
             @foreach (var item in Model.Enrollments)
             {    
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.EnrID)    
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Asgnt)<!--navigational--> 
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item. Title)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CouID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.dayOfWeek)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Actor)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.SudIDD)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item. Address)                               
               <tr>  
                  <td>  
                  @Html.ActionLink("Report", "PrintCustomers", "PdfRender", new { sName = item.Student.FirstMidName, courseTitle = item.Course.Title, sNumber = item.Student.StudentNum, instructorName = HttpContext.Current.Session["teacherName"] }, null)   
                  </td> 
                  <td>  
                     @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Student.FirstMidName)   
                  </td>  
                  <td>  
                     @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Student.LastName)
                  </td> 
                  <td>
                     @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.HomeworkGrade) 
                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().HomeworkGrade)
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.attendanceCode)
                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().attendanceCode)
                  </td>  
                  <td>  
                     @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.classDays)  
                  </td>    
              </tr>    
           }  
        </tbody> 
     </table> 
  </div>
  <br />
  <Input Type ="submit" Value="Submit Attendance"/>
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally recreated the view by having it scaffolded rather than copying the functionality of one view, pasting into another and tweaking.  I suspect it may have had something to do with navigational properties not having values or simply having  navigational properties in the view.  Please let me know what you think.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is causing your described problem but your table id is not quoted.

`<table id=history>`

Should be `<table id="history">`

Comment: I added the quotes but still the same problem...nothing happening.